# Not able initiate H2OContext on databricks , pysparkling

Tags: python, pyspark, h2o, databricks

I am trying create H2OContext in python note book on databricks cluster. Following is my environment specs:

- Databricks runtime environment: 5.3
- Spark = 2.4
- Python = 3.5
- colorama >= 0.3.8
- h2o-pysparkling-2.4

I am writing following code:

```html
from pysparkling import *

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import h2o

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparklingWaterApp").getOrCreate()

h2oConf = H2OConf(spark).set("spark.ui.enabled", "false")

hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate(spark, conf=h2oConf)`
```

I am getting this error:

```html
 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 40, 10.139.64.7, executor 2): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.h2o.backends.internal.InternalBackendUtils$; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -279081412540759760, local class serialVersionUID = -4513453206774459154

Py4JJavaError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
4 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparklingWaterApp").getOrCreate()
5 h2oConf = H2OConf(spark).set("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
----> 6 hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate(spark, conf=h2oConf)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysparkling/context.py in getOrCreate(spark, conf, verbose, pre_create_hook, h2o_connect_hook, **kwargs)
159
160 # Create backing Java H2OContext
--> 161 jhc = jvm.org.apache.spark.h2o.JavaH2OContext.getOrCreate(jspark_session, selected_conf._jconf)
162 h2o_context._jhc = jhc
163 h2o_context._conf = selected_conf

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in call(self, *args)
1255 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
1256 return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257 answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
1258
1259 for temp_arg in temp_args:
```

Please suggest.

Regards,
Bharat

Answer (score 0):

Please install a version of sparkling_water_core_2_11_2_4_x-xxxxx.jar that matches with the version of h2o installed in your databricks runtime.

Comment: Explain why this will solve the issue and also explain why the user is having an issue with existing implementation.

Comment: Hi Harish, We have installed the suggested jar file but we are still getting the same error.

Comment: Please type here: h2o version used in this run-time and the jar file version attached as well.

Comment: Please modify **sparkling_water_assembly_2_11_2_4_xx_all.jar** as well.